# Некорректный вывод размерности массива в функции

Tags: c++, массивы, sizeof

Уважаемые коллеги!

Компилятор меня не понимает. Общеизвестно, что размерность массива `int size = (sizeof(b) / sizeof(*b));`Где, b - некоторый массив. Так вот в примере ниже я получаю размерность массива вынося эту команду в отдельную функцию и выполняя эту команду в **main**:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>  

using namespace std;

//Функция которая считает и печатает размерность массива.
void ArrLength(int a[]) {
    int j = (sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a));; //определяем размерность массива
    cout << "Размерность массива в функции ArrLength = " << j << endl; 
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int b[] =  {3, 5, 8, 3, 0, 32, 18, 65}; //объявление некоторого массива
    int size = (sizeof(b) / sizeof(*b)); //выяснение размерности некоторого массива 
    cout << "Размерность массива size = " << size << endl;
    ArrLength(b);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

К моему глубочайшему удивлению, распечатывает:

```
Размерность массива size = 8
Размерность массива в функции ArrLength = 2
```

То есть, даёт два различных ответа. И если с первым я готов согласиться, то второй кажется мне явно ошибочным.

**Вопрос:** чем можно объяснить наблюдаемое поведение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Параметры функции, объявленные как массивы, неявно упорядочиваются в указатели на типы элементов массивов.

Поэтому следующие объявления функции

```
void ArrLength(int a[]);
void ArrLength(int a[100]);
void ArrLength(int *a);
```

Эквивалентны и объявляют одну и туже функцию, параметром которой будет указатель типа `int *`.

Вы все эти объявления можете одновременно включить в программу, так как одну и ту же функцию можно объявлять (в отличии от определения функции) несколько раз.

Поэтому внутри этой функции

```
void ArrLength(int a[]) {
    int j = (sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a));; //определяем размерность массива
    cout << "Размерность массива в функции ArrLength = " << j << endl; 
}
```

параметр функции `a` имеет тип `int *` и выражение

```
sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a)
```

эквивалентно выражению

```
sizeof( int * ) / sizeof( int )
```

и в зависимости от платформы будет равно либо 2 либо 1.

Если вы хотите написать самостоятельно функцию, которая будет возвращать число элементов в массиве, то вам следует написать шаблонную функцию, в которой массив передается по ссылке.

Например

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t ArrLength( const T (&a)[N] )
{
    return N;
}
```

В С++ вы можете воспользоваться структурой `std::extent` для получения количества элементов в массиве. Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    int a[4][6];

    std::cout << std::extent<decltype(a)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::extent<decltype(a), 1>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
4
6
```

Comment: Офигеть. Вопрос задан 41 минуту назад. Ответ дан 32 минуты назад. То есть вы всё подробненько за 9 минут расписали?

Comment: @AndrewKachalin Это один из часто задаваемых вопросов по C/C++, так что ответ уже пишется, как говорится, на автомате. Не надо лезть в стандарт языка, чтобы выяснять какие-либо детали.

Answer (score 4):

Тем, что при передаче в функцию массив неявно приводится к указателю. Так что вы пытаетесь выяснить `sizeof(int*)/sizeof(int)`.

Кстати, сразу видно, что вы создаете 64-разрядное приложение :)